# How to get the time difference between two times in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have two times, say `timeS = '00.00.00'` and `timeE = '10.00.00'`

I want to get the time difference between the two times. One way is the following manner,

```
//create date format          
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + timeS).getHours();
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + timeE).getHours();

var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;
```

Here, I had to get the desired result using the **Date** format. Is there any other way to achieve this, without explicitly making a **Date** object?

**Note**: Instead of marking it a `duplicate`, do observe that I am asking for some other alternative ways.

Comment: Why is making Data object so bad for you?

Comment: @NoOorZ24, No its not bad for me. All I am interested in is to find some alternative solutions. You can call it a touch of "curiosity"

Comment: `'10:00:00'.split(':').reduce((sum, curr) => sum * 60 + +curr, 0)`

Comment: Do not use the built-in parser, particularly for non–compliant strings. See  [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `hh.mm.ss` format into equivalent seconds by parsing.

```js
var timeS = '00.00.00';
var timeE = '10.00.00';

function convertToSeconds(timeString) {
    var timeSplit = timeString.split('.');
    return timeSplit.reduce((result, item, index) => {
        return result + Number(item) * Math.pow(60, timeSplit.length - index - 1)
    }, 0);
}

const secondDifference = convertToSeconds(timeE) - convertToSeconds(timeS);

console.log(secondDifference);
```

Comment: The arrow function can be reduced to `return timeSplit.reduce((result, item, index) => result + item * Math.pow(60, timeSplit.length - index), 0)`. ;-)

Comment: @Saswat just fixed a bug in this, if you copied this for use, please note.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert this `time` to a `Date` first

```
var convertToMS = time => { 
   var d = new Date(1,1,1);
   d.setHours.apply( d, time.split(".").map( Number ) );
   return d.getTime();
};

var diffOutput = convertToMS( timeE ) - convertToMS( timeS );
```

**Demo**

```js
var convertToMS = time => {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours.apply(d, time.split(".").map(Number));
  return d.getTime();
};

var timeS = '00.00.00';
var timeE = '10.00.00';

var diffOutput = convertToMS(timeE) - convertToMS(timeS);
console.log(diffOutput)
```

**Edit**

As suggested by @RobG, check this alternate solution using `UTC`

```
var convertToMS = time => Date.UTC(1,1,1, ...time.split('.'));
```

Comment: This is prone to rare bugs due to daylight saving affecting the time value. A Date object should really only be used where dates are involved.

Comment: @RobG How is the above code prone to bugs due to daylight savings. Please share.

Comment: You're setting the local time. If the first time is before the daylight saving change and the second time is after, there will be a discrepancy equal to the daylight saving offset, either minus or plus, depending on whether going into or out of daylight saving respectively.

Comment: @RobG In that case, if I change it to use `new Date(1,1,1)`, then all invocations will use the same data and given time only, right?

Comment: Yes (noting that creates a date for 1901-02-01) and assuming it doesn't coincide with a daylight saving boundary anywhere (which seems likely), or use UTC, so the function becomes `var convertToMS = time => Date.UTC(1,1,1, ...time.split('.'))`.